# how can we use or condition in october cms to check the pages

Tags: octobercms

[image]

how to use or condition for checking the page in october cms ? 
I have attached a screenshot of my code above.

Comment: Hi please check my answer below

Comment: You can refer this link for future twig related questions [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/).

Comment: You are deleting questions having downvotes, You are asking the very basic question, First understand OctoberCMS well then if you find any difficulty, we will solve them. See these videos and learn from these [OctoberCMS Videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SmnExVW0Ag&list=PLUBR53Dw-Ef-X-_A1KLy41r2QArCBy4rM)

Comment: Yes I have watching those videos

Comment: https://prnt.sc/jlj131

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use it like that

```
{% if this.page.baseFileName == 'home' or this.page.title == 'Page not found (404)' %}
```

okay I updated the answer. please check now

Comment: i am asking how to use 'or' condition in this method

Comment: you just need to use 'or' for that :)

Twig doesn't accept || or &&... Try using or and and instead.

Comment: great that worked.. i was trying to use symbols for that.. :D

Comment: this is not related to current question. you must ask it as a new question